# Get str representation of JSON to encode like print()

Tags: python, json, string

I need to pass a JSON object that looks like below to a REST API (plz note the escaped " in the value - which is json in string format)

```
{ "data": "{\"positionname\": \"API User\",\"person\": \"Paul\",}" }
```

In POSTMAN, using POST method to API endpoint with JSON above, I get 200 and a record created.  When I try to do the same from Python Shell using 'requests', it fails:

```
# JSON as string with proper escape
>>> data = '{"data": "{\\"positionname\\": \\"API User\\", \\"person\\": \\"Paul\\"}"}'
# Loads output removes backslashes
>>> json.loads(data)
{'data': '{"positionname": "API User", "person": "Paul"}'}
# Print output shows data -exactly- as I need to pass it to the API
# The string that print() provides is in the EXACT format that the API requires
# It needs " around data, and the escape \ character is needed.
>>> print (data)
{"data": "{\"positionname\": \"API User\", \"person\": \"Paul\"}"}
# Data still in original format...
>>> data
'{"data": "{\\"positionname\\": \\"API User\\", \\"person\\": \\"Paul\\"}"}'
# Try to pass the data to the API..
>>> response = apiRequest.post('http://apiURL/board/Input', data)
# It fails...
>>> response<Response [400]>
>>>
```

UPDATE:

I was able to use POSTMAN to add a record using single-quotes as show below.  However, when I try in Python, the "data" key is changed to 'data' (single quotes) and the API requires double-quotes:

```
# Now using single quotes in the JSON - sending this to POSTMAN works
>>> data = '{"data": "{\'positionname\': \'API User\', \'person\': \'X\'}"}'

# Data still looks great.
>>> data
'{"data": "{\'positionname\': \'API User\', \'person\': \'X\'}"}'

# But when I send to the API, I get an error saying that double-quotes are required at the first character - that was odd b/c they are - but when I do a json.loads() I see that the "data" is now 'data'

Error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

>>> json.loads(data)
{'data': "{'positionname': 'API User', 'person': 'X'}"}
```

^^^ why is 'data' singlequoted and the value is "{}" doublequoted?

Comment: Try repr or str, although is not clear what you want

Comment: A REST service requires the data to look exactly like:

{
    "data" : "{ \"positionname\": \"API User\", \"person\": \"Ted\" }"
}

And I can't get the backslashes to be escaped properly.

Comment: repr duplicates the backslashes.  str doesn't escape double backslashes.  And json.loads() just removes them altogether.

Comment: print(data) formats it perfectly, but there's no way to trap that output.  I've tried StringIO() but no luck.

Comment: Put another way...why does this:
json.loads('{ "data": "{\\"positionname\\": \\"API User\\",\\"person\\": \\"Paul\\",}" }')

Create this output:
{'data': '{"positionname": "API User","person": "Paul",}'}

Why doesn't the \\ output as a single backslash \ ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you understand how Python formats string literals.  In Python source code, "\\" is a 1-character string (a single backslash), because the first '\' character is the beginning of an escape sequence.  The print function doesn't do that, so `print("\\")` will output simply '\'.  So you need to clarify exactly what your input and output strings are.  One interpretation of your question is that you simply need to replace two backslashes by one backslash, which is easily done with the standard library string.replace function.

Comment: I'm editing my original post with more info...

Comment: BTW, the comma in `\"Paul\",}" }` is wrong. There should be no comma just before a `}` in JSON, and the server should reject it. If that data came from a database or user, you need to find out from them where they got it, and fix whatever code produced it, and fix that at the source.

Comment: Beyond that, though, `'{ "data": "{\\"positionname\\": \\"API User\\",\\"person\\": \\"Paul\\",}" }'
` **already is** the string representation of the data `{ "data": "{\"positionname\": \"API User\",\"person\": \"Paul\",}" }
`. No further conversion is needed, because that's the data you already have.

Comment: I know....it's totally bizarre, but its what the vendor requires.  I need to push data to a REST service in this format.  I don't have control over the service.

And yes, I removed the last comma in previous iterations of testing.  I found that as well, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you send your string over the wire, it's sent over the wire **as literal data**, not a Python-syntax representation, so it's already sent in the same format emitted by `print()`. **There is no further conversion needed**.

Comment: Let me try again with your comma suggestion.  I did get to the point where json.loads() threw an error.

Comment: (and no, the data format your vendor is requesting isn't particularly bizarre -- it's just double JSON encoding. Requiring that usually means someone screwed up their API design, but people screw up API design quite often, so it's a common thing).

Comment: I added the json.loads() output which removes the backslashes altogether.

Comment: @dizzyguy, that's normal, correct and expected, because it's showing you the **Python representation** instead of the **JSON representation**. The  backslashes are only needed in the JSON representation (and they're _double_ backslashes in the Python representation of that JSON representation).

Comment: @dizzyguy, ...`repr()` will, when given a string that contains double quotes as literal data, put single quotes outside it instead. JSON can't do that, so it keeps double quotes on the outside and adds slashes before the literal ones on the inside. Got it?

Comment: Ok but I can only get a 200 OK if I use POSTMAN and post the exact string in #1.

If I try to push the 'data' above to the service, it throws a 400 error.

Comment: To be clear, you've made enough mistakes trying to understand which string is encoded how that it's hard for me to trust your assertions unless you show the exact code you used to push the string via postman in both working and broken cases.

Comment: {
    "data" : "{ \"positionname\": \"SAA IPS\", \"person\": \"Ted\" }"
}

Comment: That creates a record with a POST.  The above is the body.

Comment: When I say "the exact code you used to push the string", I'm not just asking for the representation of the string; I'm asking for _how you used it_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238399/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-dizzyguy).

Comment: I don't think I follow - just using postman.  POST method.  URL endpoint.  JSON data.   And it works.

Comment: @-notice @Charles I added more directly from the shell.  Tried to post using python requests library.  So close...

Comment: That post looks to me (without knowing the API you're trying to use) like it really should have worked. That said -- what type of object is `apiRequest`?

Comment: I might spend some time making sure your headers are right -- f/e, `Content-Type: application/json` and the like.

Comment: ...also, have you actually inspected the body of your HTTP 400 response? If there's a more specific error message from the server in there, you don't want to ignore it.

Comment: `headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}`, to be specific, assuming that `apiRequest` follows the `requests` API.

Comment: Thank you Charles -- so the 400 error is Bad Request and the server doesn't log errors.   You are correct the apiRequest is requests.session() and I do have all of my headers set.  In fact, I'm able to do various queries against the REST API - it's just this weird instance (POST) that's the issue.

Comment: @-notice @Charles made a tiny bit of progress.  I don't need the escape \" as I was told by them - I can use single quotes.  But, there is a problem with the first "data" element - when I output the JSON, it formats it with single-quotes.  I need it to retain the double quotes ".  Please see ex above.

Comment: I already explained that to you multiple times. I don't think repeating myself again is likely to be fruitful. The single quotes are part of _the Python representation_, not the actual literal data. When you pass a string for `data`, it's the _literal data_ that gets sent to the server; the way Python represents that data at a repl (or, in your case, in VS Code) is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Instead of going back and forth on this again and again, why don't you grab a packet sniffer like Wireshark and look at the actual data sent over the wire? That way you can put packet captures from the Postman case and the Python case next to each other to compare.

Comment: Honestly -- while this isn't something I usually agree to do for strangers, I'm _almost_ considering asking if you might be up for a 1:1 screen share so we can stop going around in circles. If you're up for that, reach out out-of-band; my contact info isn't hard to find. (That said, I'm about to be on a bicycle for the next hour-and-change, so no knowing exactly how scheduling will work out).

Comment: I'll take you up on that...and if you are on your bike I get it.  I had to escape for a swim hoping it'd clear my head.

Comment: Before we go that far, actually -- https://postb.in/ might be an interim step without as much learning involved as using a packet sniffer.

Comment: Got it...  go enjoy the ride.  I'm not going to take up more of your time.  Thanks again!

Comment: Had a good ride; I'm home now. After actually poking at postb.in, I've come to the conclusion that it's a little bit buggy right now, and that https://requestbin.com/ is a superior alternative.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you're available to debug interactively, ping me -- I'm comfortable that we can work through this (and I just added test steps to my answer, to let you see what it's actually sending to the server, vs how the Python represents that text).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "trap" the output of `print()`; you *already have* the data.

`print()` prints *the actual data as it really exists*, which is distinct from the `repr()`esentation of that data encoded in Python syntax.

Similarly, a call like `file.write(yourdata)` or `socket.send(yourdata)` will send that literal data, not the Python representation thereof.

---

If it's in your control, the logic you use to generate your string should look like this:

```
content = { "positionname": "API User", "person": "Paul" }
wrapper = { "data": json.dumps(content) }
wrapper_json = json.dumps(wrapper)
```

...if you `print(wrapper_json)`, you'll see something formatted in exactly the right way to send to your service.

---

We can demonstrate the above by posting to a publicly available pastebin and retrieving its response:

```py
import requests, json, sys

position = "API User"
username = "Paul"

## FIXME: CHANGE THIS TO YOUR OWN PUBLIC REQUESTBIN INSTANCE
requestbin = 'https://enh4cydill4ac.x.pipedream.net'

content = { "positionname": position, "person": username }
wrapper = { "data": json.dumps(content) }
wrapper_json = json.dumps(wrapper)

response = requests.post(requestbin,
                         data=wrapper_json,
                         headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

Asking requestbin for the raw body of this request, it tells us that the text the client sent to the server is:

```json
{"data": "{\"positionname\": \"API User\", \"person\": \"Paul\"}"}
```

...which is exactly what we expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case looks strange, but if you don't find any satisfactory solution you can try this to get desired output.

```
data = '{ "data": "{\\"positionname\\": \\"API User\\",\\"person\\": \\"Paul\\",}" }'

dataSplitted = data.split("\\")

output = ""

for word in dataSplitted:
    output = "{}\{}".format(output, word)

output = output[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks but that also didn't work.  New issue in the UPDATE above.  Not sure whey double-quotes are converted to single quotes in the JSON.